# Update last checked ^ 1

Tags: updates, nexus-7, system

When I navigate to settings -> about tablet -> system updates, it tells me updates were last checked "^ 1" instead of giving a date and time like I expected. Clicking on check now does apparently nothing. It's been like this since updating this Nexus 7 to 4.4.4. What does it mean and can I get it to show something meaningful instead?

After changing the language to English (United Kingdom), it now displays a time, and check now updates the timestamp. Placeholder error in the translation template, perhaps? Should I report this error somewhere?

Comment: What is your system language?. Try changing the language to English and check.

Comment: @sameer Finnish, I changed it to British English now and it seems to work. Translation placeholder error? Should I report it somewhere?

Comment: Sorry I don't know where to report it ?

Comment: What ROM are you running, stock or custom? If its custom, then post on the developers website. If its stock, then first read this [Android Bug Reporting](https://source.android.com/source/report-bugs.html). There several important things. First is to search for the same bug, then how to have a *"good"* bug report. And where to report it.